# How can we convert an html file to sharepoint2010 site page

Tags: sharepoint

How can we convert an html file to sharepoint and how can we uplaod and apply the css and jQuery files to the share point site..please help me on this

Answer (score 0):

HTML files cannot be converted to Sharepoint page on Sharepoint2010. if you have styles on the  page its advisible to upload the same (incl .css and .js) on one document library and provide the ref on the uploaded HTML page . or else you can use that HTML on an Article page which you create , add a Content editor webpart and paste those HTML scripts with .css and .js reference on that

Hope this helps

Regards
Arjun